# How to match an entity that have an empty relation in STRAPI v4

Tags: javascript, rest, strapi

I use strapi `v4` and I need to match the `authors` that have no `books`. The relation is `Authors belongs to many books`. I need to do that through REST API.

I tried something like:

```
{
  filters: {
    orders: []
  }
}
```

This is a valid filter, but it returns me an empty array, even though there are entities that apparently should match it.

As I said, there needs to do it through REST API. In particular i call this api in GET with the url `{HOST}/api/profiles?qs.stringify(filters)` where *HOST* is the server endpoint.

So do you have any suggestion on what to try in order to get those Authors that have no books?